# How to configure ElasticSearch to consider accents?

Tags: magento2, search, elasticsearch

I'm using ElasticSearch 6 and Magento 2.3, and when I search **Hélicopter** it does not return the products **Helicopter** without the accent.

I found [this](https://discuss.elastic.co/t/problem-searching-queries-with-accents/6401) possible solution saying to change the 'term' query to 'text' query.

How could I configure it in my Magento installation? Am I able to do it via the admin panel?